# Are user scoped application settings (created in the VS designer) thread safe?

Tags: c#, application-settings, thread-synchronization

I have created application settings in my visual studio project, containing both user scoped settings and application scoped settings. My application has several threads that may access the settings for read or write simultaneously. I've searched MSDN to see whether the user scoped settings which can be updated in run time are thread safe, but couldn't find a definite answer. Does anybody know?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It depends on what you mean by thread safety here. They're not thread safe in the following scenario: `int current = Settings.Default.SomeIndex; current++; Settings.Default.SomeIndex = current; Settings.Default.Save();`

Answer (score 3):

Thread-safety is much more than just "will this corrupt the data structure."

In the context of settings, there are three distinct meanings you need to consider. The settings data structure is safe in one of them, but not in the other two.

1. Setting and reading individual values
2. Setting and reading several values at the same time, getting or setting a consistent picture
3. Adjusting a value by using its current value to calculate the new one before setting it back

In the first case, yes, the settings data structure is thread safe. You will not be able to write a half-Int64 into the settings and risking that another thread observes that half-way value.

However, if you're setting several values sequentially, you're not guaranteed another thread is not able to read all the settings between two such set-statements, observing one change, but not the other.

In other words, you can have this scenario:

```
Thread 1                       Thread 2
set setting 1
                               read setting 1
                               read setting 2
set setting 2
```

And in the case of reading a value, calculating a new value from the value you read, and setting it back, there's no guarantee that another thread hasn't been able to do the same (ie. change the current value) in the meantime.

Like this:

```
Thread 1                       Thread 2
read setting 1
                               read setting 1
                               calculate new value
                               write setting 1
calculate new value
write setting 1
```

For the latter two scenarios, you need an external synchronization object you can lock on to ensure you're not getting half-way changes, or losing changes, but then all code accessing the settings in this manner will need to lock on that object.

Comment: I only have the first scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

The wrapper generated by the Visual Studio applications settings designer is a synchronized singleton with an indexer that will get and set application settings properties in a thread-safe manner.